# Realtek ALC256: no soundcards found

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, realtek

I had a problem with sound, so tried to fix it according to answers already here. None of them worked for me and actually made it even worse!

I deleted pulse setting as recommended in one of the answers here

```
$ rm -rf ~/.conf/pulse
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, when I run

```
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

Sounds settings show "**Dummy output**"

I tried to reinstall `alsa-base`, `pulseaudio` but it didn't help.

```
$ alsamixer
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
$ pulseaudio -D
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

EDIT: Now even Windows on the same machine doesn't recognize the device, so there might be a problem with device but I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

*(I already posted this reply here: [Mint Forums Post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=373391))*

Hi, I'm not sure if you are still looking for a fix to this issue, but thank God and all the amazing people who researched this, I found a fix after a few tough days of research. I have an LG Gram 17 with ALC256 and Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu) and both my speakers and microphones were not detected. I made a video tutorial on how to fix it, and I also wrote a guide. If you want the video, here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vz6jDUyn7S0

*Here is a guide I wrote (at your own risk!) on how to fix the issue step by step if you don't want to watch the video:*

**Step 1 - Remove (backup) the old SOF drivers from your system:**
a) `sudo mv /lib/firmware/intel/sof* ~/Desktop/old-sof-backup`
b) `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sof-* ~/Desktop/old-sof-backup`

**Step 2 - Download and install the newer drivers from the SOF Project Github repo:**
Link: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin

a) Open the directory for your desired SOF version in terminal, let's assume v2.1.1.
b) `sudo rsync -a sof*v2.1.1 /lib/firmware/intel/`
c) `sudo ln -s sof-v2.1.1 /lib/firmware/intel/sof`
d) `sudo ln -s sof-tplg-v2.1.1 /lib/firmware/intel/sof-tplg`
e) `sudo rsync tools-v2.1.1/* /usr/local/bin`

(If you don't want to use symbolic links, refer to the repository for instructions on how to install the drivers without symbolic links)

**Step 3 - Download and install the fixes/patches from the following SOF Project Github repo:**
Link: https://github.com/thesofproject/alsa-ucm-conf/tree/sof_ucm1

(Remove the old `"/usr/share/alsa/ucm"` directory and replace it with the newly downloaded one from the repo)
a) `sudo rm -r /usr/share/alsa/ucm`
b) `sudo mv ./ucm /usr/share/alsa`

**Step 4 - REBOOT**
After you reboot, all your speakers, microphones and everything will show up and will be working. HOWEVER, the microphone input and speakers volume will be lower than usual. Step 5-6 are the fix for this.

**Step 5 - Raise the input/output volume using ALSAMIXER (after rebooting!)**
a) Open alsamixer in terminal.
b) Press F5 to show all devices.
c) Raise everything (or what you need) to the maximum value possible.

**Step 6 - Save the ALSAMIXER settings permanently for each reboot**
(we use the first "store" command once to store the settings in the designated file, then each time you reboot, the "restore" command will restore the settings from this file)

a) `alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state store`
b) Set the command `alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state restore` to run automatically on each startup so that the stored alsamixer settings in step 6(a) are always restored.

Cheers to the lads here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249900&p=4